# How to add subject to sendmail function

Tags: ksh, sendmail

I have the below line code in ksh:

```
echo -e "$SUBJECT"|/usr/sbin/sendmail -f XXXXXX@gmail.com -t XXXXXX@gmail.com
```

but I'm still getting the `$SUBJECT` in the body, and not as the real subject. what's wrong with it?

Comment: If `SUBJECT` contains characters which are interpreted by `echo -e`, that's probably the reason this isn't working. If not, you should probably still not use `echo -e` here.

Comment: You don't want a `-t` option if your message doesn't contain the addressing headers. You seem to misunderstand what this option does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's sometimes easier to send all the headers in the `echo`

e.g.

```
{
  echo From: xxxx
  echo To: yyyy
  echo Subject: Foobar
  echo 
  echo This is the message
} | /usr/lib/sendmail -t
```

Comment: Actually I would use some mail program instead of an MTA to create an initial submission.

Comment: @U.Windl "sendmail" is an MSA in this context

Answer (score 1):

Subject is part of the headers, try:

```
echo -e "Subject:$SUBJECT" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -f XXXXXX@gmail.com -t XXXXXX@gmail.com
```

Comment: how do I add body for it?

Comment: @arielma The answer by Stephen Harris shows how to do that (add an empty line and then the body).

Answer (score 1):

You really want to avoid `echo -e` here. In fact, there are several reasons to prefer `printf`, not the least of which is simply convenience.

```bsh
printf '%s\n' "Subject: $subject" \
   "From: I am a Sender <sender@example.net>" \
   "To: Recipient <victim@example.org>" \
   "" \
   "This is the body of the message." \
   "It spans multiple lines." |
sendmail -oi -t
```

The empty line (`""`) separates the headers from the message body. A trivial SMTP message is just plain text, US-ASCII only.

This is still quite limited in what it can do. If you need to use non-ASCII character sets or nontrivial MIME structures, you really don't want to paste strings one after another. Some versions of `mail` or `mailx` allow you to assemble proper MIME messages with attachments, or maybe look at e.g. `mutt` if you have more complex needs.

Common mistakes include

- a weird insistence on omitting the space before the `<` in the address headers, or putting weird quoting around some of the header fields
- forgetting the empty line between headers and body
- not understanding that the body (in the absence of more MIME headers) is just plain text, not HTML or multipart
- putting really long lines in the body (SMTP permits a little under 1000 characters per line; again, use proper MIME encapsulation to break this limit)
- trying to use Unicode without declaring a character set (you guessed it, learn and use MIME to do that)

Notice also [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -e "Subject:$sub" |sendmail -f linuser@qcsp1app1.com -t arjun.karunakirinathan@gmail.com. < body_detail.txt
```